# mysqli_stmt_bind_param: type mismatch do not raise error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a php application I try and succed in using mysqli with that function :

```
function executeUpdateInsert($SQLStatement, $SQLBindString, $bindValueArray){
$ret = -1;
$dbConnection = getDbConnection();
$stmt =  mysqli_prepare( $dbConnection, $SQLStatement);
$bindParamArray = array_merge(array($stmt, $SQLBindString), $bindValueArray );
call_user_func_array ( mysqli_stmt_bind_param , $bindParamArray );

if( mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ) {
    $ret = mysqli_insert_id ($dbConnection);    
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    $dbConnection->close();
}else{
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    $dbConnection->close();
}
return $ret;
}
```

The function call looks like :

```
executeUpdateInsert( "UPDATE mytable(int1, int2, string2)VALUES (?,?,?)", "iis", array ( 12,42,"string") ) );
```

This is actually working althought I find a very strange behaviour of that when I try to insert non integer like `125r896` value inside the database. In a perfect world I would expect that `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)` return `FALSE` and fail, but no it inserts 125 in the integer field instead.

Am i doing something incorrectly or is it the normal behaviour of the statement object in PHP + MySQL?
Because I cleary considere that as a bug and not a feature.

Comment: it's casting the value `125r896` to an int, and that gives you the 125.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` does not *validate* your data, it forces the data to a type.  You need to validate that your data is what you expect.

Comment: I definitely hate PHP.  Thank you.

Comment: If you need data validation, you probably want an ORM like [Doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/).

Comment: The smaller it is, the easier it'll be to use an ORM.